# Do lowpass filters affect the integral over the signal?

Tags: lowpass-filter

For which filters, does the resulting signal have the same integral (/average) as the original? Obviously this is true for a moving average, but is it also mathematically true for e.g. a Butterworth filter?

I am trying to build a lowpass filter for a signal of measurement samples. While there is a lot of noise, the average (over a sizable number of samples) is correct. I need to filter it retaining that property, regardless of the input frequency spectrum.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need a filter whose transfer function evaluated at 0 (DC component) is 1, or equivalently, whose impulse response sums to 1.

Comment: Also, you can make that the case for any low-pass filter by dividing the filter's coefficients by the sum of the coefficients.

Comment: In general it seems to look like this holds for Butterworth filters considering their Gain definition. But I guess it actually depends on the actual filter design (approximation)? So lets say I create a Butterworth 4th. with sample rate 1Hz, corner 0.0225 Hz using this page: http://www-users.cs.york.ac.uk/~fisher/mkfilter/trad.html. Now the coefficients add up to 1, the picture looks good, but it says "gain at dc    :   mag = 4.787085439e+04", shouldn't this be 1?

Comment: Sorry- I should have said in my comment above that you can do that for any FIR filter.  You can also set the gain of an IIR filter to 1, but it's a little more tricky.  For an IIR filter I would break it up into the various stages and set each of their gains to 1.

Comment: @Jim Clay: I'm afraid that I don't design the filter myself, so breaking up in stages is beyond my current abilities. However it would be sufficient for me to *confirm* in a mathematical solid sense that a filter from a library/toolbox/the page i mentioned has this property.